# DotNet Core Xunit Always Went to Catchblock

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit

When i call the api through postman the data successfully inserted on mongodb. But i am running the xunit test class it shows mongodb null exception. Why i getting this problem. The following is my test class and the project source code.

XUnit

```
    [Fact]
    public async void Test1()
    {
        JObject jObject = new JObject();
        jObject.Add("name", "Satheesh");
        jObject.Add("email", "sat@sat.com");

        JObject finaljObject = new JObject();
        finaljObject.Add("data", jObject);

        Console.WriteLine("************ "+finaljObject);
        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finaljObject);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        // Act
        var response = await _client.PostAsync("/api/Values/User", stringContent);

        // Assert
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Assert.Contains("Data Successfully Retrived", responseString);
    }
```

Projcet Source

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMongoDatabase _database = null;
        // GET api/values


        public ValuesController(IOptions<Settings> settings)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);
                if (client != null)
                    _database = client.GetDatabase(settings.Value.Database);
            }
            catch(MongoException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DB Connection Error "+e.StackTrace);
            }
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [Route("User")]
        public async Task <dynamic> RegisterUser([FromBody] JObject value)
        {
            //User Registeration
            BsonDocument ReturnData = new BsonDocument();
            try
            {
                dynamic jObject = JObject.FromObject(value);
                dynamic data = jObject.data;
                BsonDocument Document = BsonDocument.Parse(data.ToString());
                _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("User").InsertOne(Document);
                if(Document["_id"].AsObjectId != null)
                {                    
                    return ReturnData.Add("message","Successfully Inserted").Add("Success",1).Add("data",Document["_id"].AsObjectId).ToJson();
                }
                else
                {
                    return ReturnData.Add("message","Error During Insert Document").Add("Success",0).ToJson();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                return ReturnData.Add("message","Error").Add("Success",e.StackTrace).ToJson();
            }
        }
   }
```

Error:

```
 DB Connection Error    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.Ensure.IsNotNull[T](T value, String paramName)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrlBuilder.Parse(String url)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl..ctor(String url)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor(String connectionString)
   at test3.Controllers.ValuesController..ctor(IOptions`1 settings)
```

How to solve this problem. Any one try to help me.

Thank you...

Comment: How do you initialize the `Settings` option when creating TestServer? I guess the reason is you're creating a TestServer which doesn't have the settings configured rightly.

Comment: This is the way i did it .private readonly HttpClient _client;

            public UnitTest1()
            {
                _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
                                        .UseStartup<Startup>());
                _client = _server.CreateClient();
            }

Comment: When i debug the code the value not get from the appsettings file

Comment: I'm not pretty sure, but I'm testing your code now and I guess the reason is that you're configuring the `Settings` option from the `appsetting.json`, but the startup won't load that since your project root has been changed to test project .

Comment: can you tell any solution for it

Comment: I use the `services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration)` , and reproduce the same error info as yours. How did you configure the `Settings` option? Something like `services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration)` ?

Comment: ya i did as you mentioned.The configuration is located in the method ConfigureServices in Startup class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the reason is your `Test Project` doesn't configure the `Settings` options.

In your `Startup` of your main project ( let's call it `App Project`), you configure the option by:

```
services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration)
```

The `Startup` doesn't load the `appsettings.json` itself. The `HostBuilder` loads it and injects the `Configuration` into the `Startup` for your.

Let's review your Test project :

```
private readonly HttpClient _client; 
public UnitTest1() { 
    _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
    _client = _server.CreateClient(); 
}
```

**The Test project did not set up a `Configuration` for `TestServer` at all**.

To fix this bug, you need build the `Configuration` for your `WebHostBuilder` in your Test project :

```
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
         // ... load the config file manually  
         //   , or copy your appsettings.json file to the test project
         //   , and custom it as you like
        .SetBasePath("path/to/your/App/proj")    
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

    var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseConfiguration(configuration)
        .UseStartup<App.Startup>();

    var server = new TestServer(builder);
    _client = server.CreateClient();
```

Comment: In the constructor section i getting the error Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ArgumentException
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll but was not handled in user code: 'The path must be absolute.'
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions.SetBasePath(IConfigurationBuilder builder, String basePath)
   at test3.Tests.UnitTest1..ctor()

Comment: @SATHEESHP The `BasePath` needs to be an absolute path.

Comment: @SATHEESHP By the way, your action method returns `"Successfully Inserted"` if successfully creates a new record, but your test asserts `Assert.Contains("Data Successfully Retrived", responseString);`. You need also fix that typo before run the test.